# Understanding cryptocurrency buying and selling calculations

Tags: foreign-exchange, cryptocurrency, bid-ask

I need to understand how buying / selling works in crypto markets.

I see an `ask` of `amount: 44608.01, rate: 0.98` in the XRP/USD market in Kraken.

1. Will the rate `0.98` be in USD or XRP? I'm assuming USD for now.
2. If I buy `44608.01 XRP/USD @ USD 0.98`, I have `USD 43715.8498`, correct?
3. If I sell `43715.8498 XRP/USD @ USD 1.13`, how many XRPs do I have?

   `43715.8498 / 1.13 = 38686.5927433628` ?
4. If my above assumptions are correct, have I then lost `44608.01 - 38686.5927433628 = 5921.4172` XRPs from these 2 transactions?
5. If I'm right on (4), how did I lose money when my buying price was lower than my selling price?

Comment: @HartCO - My understanding was that if I place a buy of 44608.01 on XRP/USD, I have spent 44608.01 XRP to purchase 43715.8498 USD, am I wrong?

Comment: So.  For starters.  You don't buy or sell XRP/USD.  You're either buying ripple or you're buying bitcoin or your buying dollars.  That order is for 44608 Ripple priced in USD at $0.98USD per Ripple.  (though make sure it's really USD not USDT tether).  It looks like you bought 44608 then sold only 43715 and you haven't accounted for fees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I buy 44608.01 XRP/USD @ USD 0.98, I have USD 43715.8498, correct?

No, you used to have $43,715.85, now you have 44,608.01 XRP.

> If I sell 43715.8498 XRP/USD @ USD 1.13, how many XRPs do I have?

44608.01 - 43715.8498 = 892.1602. You have 892.1602 XRP (and $49,398.91 proceeds from the sale).

> If my above assumptions are correct, have I then lost 44608.01 - 38686.5927433628 = 5921.4172 XRPs from these 2 transactions?

No, you've gained $4,790.90 (and you hold 892.1602 XRP with a present value of another $1008.14).

Answer (score 2):

> Will the rate 0.98 be in USD or XRP? I'm assuming USD for now. 
> If I
>   buy 44608.01 XRP/USD @ USD 0.98, I have USD 43715.8498, correct? 
> If I
>   sell 43715.8498 XRP/USD @ USD 1.13, how many XRPs do I have?

An 'ask' means an offer to sell 44,608.01 XRP for $0.98/each.

So it would cost $43,715.85 to buy all 44,608.01 XRP, if you subsequently sold them at $1.13/each you'd have $50,407.05 and 0 XRP (and capital gain of $6,691).